# Adjusting vertical skip between equations

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
  \end{equation}
  \begin{align}
    7 + 5 &= 12\\
    12 &= 11 + 1
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Can one adjust the skip between the first and second equation to equal that between the second and third?

Comment: I would advise against chaining equation-like environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an unorthodox solution: insert an `align` environment in a `gather` environment. I don't know if there are any side effects, in particular with cross-references. The orthodox way would be to group the aligned equations within an … `aligned` environment, but there will be one number for both. With the code you posted, the result is particularly unaesthetic, but I suppose the real equations will be somewhat different:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

  \begin{gather}
    1 + 1 = 2\\
  \begin{align}
    7 + 5 &= 12\\
    12 &= 11 + 1
  \end{align}
  \end{gather}

  \begin{gather}
    1 + 1 = 2\\
  \begin{aligned}
    7 + 5 &= 12\\
    12 &= 11 + 1
  \end{aligned}
  \end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem, though, if one labels equations 2 and 3.

Comment: In the first solution, I guess? That's what I said: I didn't test any possible side-effects

Answer (score 2):

Not in the manual, but, hey, it works!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\multispan{2}\hfill$\displaystyle 1 + 1 = 2$\hfill \label{A} \\
  7 + 5 &= 12+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1 \label{B} \\
     12 &= 11 + 1 \label{C}
\end{align}
Equations \eqref{A}, \eqref{B} and \eqref{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made my exsample less minimal and more like what I am actually doing. see new quæstion, where the first æquation is split.

Comment: @egreg: (+1) I didn't know that one!  Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @Bernard Under “very very dirty tricks”.