# Problem with gather and labels

Tags: amsmath

This gives a way of combining two different math environments (so there is no extra vertical skip):

[Adjusting vertical skip between equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292207/adjusting-vertical-skip-between-equations/292211?noredirect=1#comment707657_292211)

But add labels to that exsample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \begin{split}
    1 + 1 = 2\\
    1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 7!
  \end{split}\\
  \begin{align}
    7 + 5 &= 12\label{a}\\
    12 &= 11 + 1\label{b}
  \end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

and a problem occurs:

`! Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'a' will be lost.`

What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aligned`, together with the trick in the previous answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\multispan{2}\hfill$
  {\begin{aligned}
   & 1 + 1 = 2\\
   & 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 7!
  \end{aligned}}
  $\hfill \label{A} \\
  7 + 5 &= 12+1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1 \label{B} \\
     12 &= 11 + 1 \label{C}
\end{align}
Equations \eqref{A}, \eqref{B} and \eqref{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `align` inside `gather` ... With combination of `align` and `split` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\begin{split}
                    1 + 1 & = 2\\
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 & = 7!
\end{split}                         \label{eq:a}   \\
                    7 + 5 & = 12    \label{eq:b}   \\
                       12 & = 11 + 1\label{eq:c}
    \end{align}
Equations \eqref{eq:a}, \eqref{eq:b} and \eqref{eq:c} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]